# C# | Use parameter in SqlCommand query

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core, parameters, sqlcommand

I have this ASP.NET Core project and in my DAL I collect my data from my database, but I want the user to be able to type a type character (Karakter is character in Dutch) and the DAL should pick 2 random characters from the database with KarakterSoort = "Defensive".

This is my current code in my DAL:

```
public IEnumerable<IKarakter> GetSortedKarakters()
{
    using (SqlConnection connection = GetConnection())
    {
        connection.Open();
        var command = new SqlCommand("SELECT TOP 2 * FROM Karakter WHERE KarakterSoort = 'Defensive' ORDER BY NEWID();", connection);
        var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        var sortedKarakters = new List<IKarakter>();

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            var karakter = new KarakterDTO
            {
                KarakterId = (int)reader["KarakterId"],
                KarakterSoort = reader["KarakterSoort"]?.ToString(),
                KarakterNaam = reader["KarakterNaam"]?.ToString()
            };

            sortedKarakters.Add(karakter);
        }

        return sortedKarakters;
    }
}
```

And this is what I think should be in the right direction of the solution:

```
public IEnumerable<IKarakter> GetSortedKarakters(string givenStringFromUser)
{
    using (SqlConnection connection = GetConnection())
    {
        connection.Open();
        var command = new SqlCommand("SELECT TOP 2 * FROM Karakter WHERE KarakterSoort = givenStringFromUser ORDER BY NEWID();", connection);
        var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        var sortedKarakters = new List<IKarakter>();

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            var karakter = new KarakterDTO
            {
                KarakterId = (int)reader["KarakterId"],
                KarakterSoort = reader["KarakterSoort"]?.ToString(),
                KarakterNaam = reader["KarakterNaam"]?.ToString()
            };

            sortedKarakters.Add(karakter);
        }

        return sortedKarakters;
    }
}
```

I can't find how to make this work so I figured I ask my question here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a `SqlParameter` and set its value:

```
public IEnumerable<IKarakter> GetSortedKarakters(string givenStringFromUser)
{
    using (SqlConnection connection = GetConnection())
    {
        var command = new SqlCommand("SELECT TOP 2 * FROM Karakter WHERE KarakterSoort = @UserInput ORDER BY NEWID();", connection);
        command.Parameters.Add("@UserInput", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = givenStringFromUser;

        connection.Open();
        var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        var sortedKarakters = new List<IKarakter>();

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            var karakter = new KarakterDTO
            {
                KarakterId = (int)reader["KarakterId"],
                KarakterSoort = reader["KarakterSoort"]?.ToString(),
                KarakterNaam = reader["KarakterNaam"]?.ToString()
            };

            sortedKarakters.Add(karakter);
        }

        connection.Close();

        return sortedKarakters;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to provide your filter value to the sql query. Also, don't put it directly to query string, but use `SqlCommand` parameters. That will save you for the unwanted sql injection.

Something like this should work:

```
public IEnumerable<IKarakter> GetSortedKarakters(string givenStringFromUser)
{
    using (SqlConnection connection = GetConnection())
    {
        connection.Open();
        var command = new SqlCommand("SELECT TOP 2 * FROM Karakter WHERE KarakterSoort = @filterValue ORDER BY NEWID();", connection);
        command.Parameters.Add("@filterValue", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = givenStringFromUser;
        
        var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        var sortedKarakters = new List<IKarakter>();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            var karakter = new KarakterDTO
            {
                KarakterId = (int)reader["KarakterId"],
                KarakterSoort = reader["KarakterSoort"]?.ToString(),
                KarakterNaam = reader["KarakterNaam"]?.ToString()
            };
            sortedKarakters.Add(karakter);
        }
        return sortedKarakters;
    }
}
```